# Django Models Number Field

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, model, numbers

In Django I'm trying to create a model which will contain a field for player's shirt numbers and was wondering if there is a way to restrict the field to be only numerical inputs. Currently I have in the models.py

```
number = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

Is there a different field to CharField that will allow me to restrict the input to only numbers?

Comment: Of course. The [IntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField).

Comment: Knew it would be a simple answer. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, although I think it would be better if you checked the official documentation before posting a stackoverflow question. There are about a dozen built-in fields, you can easily go through them yourself.

Comment: `PositiveSmallIntegerField` should feet even better it takes integer values from 0 to 32767.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One of the cool things about Django that it provides you with different types of models read about them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/).

For your case try something like this

```
number = models.IntegerField()
```

You can read more about the `IntegerField` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#integerfield)

Answer (score 3):

**Player's shirt numbers** should need **only positive numbers**.

[**PositiveBigIntegerField**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#positivebigintegerfield) allows values **from 0 to 9223372036854775807**:

```py
number = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
```

[**PositiveIntegerField**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield) allows values **from 0 to 2147483647**:

```py
number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

[**PositiveSmallIntegerField**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#positivesmallintegerfield) allows values **from 0 to 32767**:

```py
number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

In addition, there are no **"NegativeIntegerField"**, **"NegativeBigIntegerField"** and **"NegativeSmallIntegerField"** in **Django**.

Answer (score 0):

There a number of fields rather than CharField in Django either in case of models or modelfields you use for forms:

In case of Integers you use: **number = models.IntegerField()**

or even

**number = models.FloatField()**, in case you want to represent price of a specific commodity.Its usefull in billing softwares.

There is also somemore like ***BigInteger*** field in case you wanted more nos

For detailed reference check:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using serializers, you can use validators for these cases. For example, for a 10-digit CharField, you can have a validator like this :

```
def postalcode_validator(value):
    rule = re.compile(r'^\d{10}$')
    if not rule.search(value):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Postal code format must be XXXXXXXXXX")
    return value
```

Then, you can use this validator with your serializer's CharField:

```
# serializers.py
...
postal_code = serializers.CharField(validators=[postalcode_validator])
```

Moreover, validators can be used with model fields as well just like the above example.